# Delete Table Rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have a `Table` in my Excel. The table is called `Table1`.

I want to delete the entire row except 1st row of the table which it can be done manually like select the row then delete table row, but I couldn't imagine if the row is reaching more than a million records. I tried the following code:

```
Sheet3.Range("A20","E500000").Delete 2
```

But the code above is error. The error said:

> This won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet.

Does anyone have a same problem with me? Suggestion please.

Comment: Do you wish to leave just the headers or the headers + 1 data row?

Comment: yes, @QHarr... header + 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below if you only have one `Table` object in your sheet.

```
Dim lo As ListObject

With Sheet3 '/* sheet code name */
    Set lo = .ListObjects(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    lo.DataBodyRange.Delete xlUp
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

If not, you can explicitly identify your table like:

```
Set lo = .ListObjects("Table1")
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to delete all the rows except the header, if so, you can use DataBodyRange like this:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Since @Haminteu want to keep the header and first row of data, I provide the solution as below.

```
With Range("Table1")
  .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Delete 2
End With
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

so the second row of the table start from cell A20?
if so, you just want to delete row till the last cell, then the code:

```
Sub dr()
Dim a As Integer

a = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range(Range("A20"), Range("A" & a)).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the 2nd row. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>. This will select all the records except the header.
Right click and select delete.